# Direct Composition has very high CPU and GPU usage

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, direct2d, direct-composition

I have a Direct Composition swap chain as the root visual of my window. I want to draw semi transparent custom controls over the swap chain, so I use an `IDCompositionVirtualSurface` as the content of a child visual and on every frame call `IDCompositionSurface::BeginDraw()` to obtain an `ID2D1DeviceContext` pointer, render the controls, then `IDCompositionSurface::EndDraw()` and `IDCompositionDevice::Commit()`. This however results in very high CPU and GPU usage (according to Task Manager rendering the controls with the swap chain directly typically uses ~2% CPU and ~0.5 GPU, the numbers easily go up to ~20% if the above method is used). Is this expected behavior? Is this the intended use case for Direct Composition?
The rendering code looks like this:

```
ID2D1DeviceContext*   pDC;
IDXGISwapChain*       pSC;
IDCompositionSurface* pDCompSurface;
IDCompositionDevice*  pDCompDevice;
VOID OnPaint()
{
    POINT               pt;
    ID2D1DeviceContext* pDCompDC;

    pDC->BeginDraw();
    //Draw bottom content here with pDC
    pDCompSurface->BeginDraw(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDCompDC), &pt);
    //Draw top content here with pDCompDC
    pDCompSurface->EndDraw();

    pDCompDC->Release();
    pDCompDevice->Commit();

    pDC->EndDraw();
    pSC->Present(1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe a very interesting question. However, I think we'll need more details and/or clarification as to what your problem is and what you've tried to resolve it.

Comment: @AdrianMole My goal is to overlay two bitmaps on each frame to produce the final content on screen (For example, a static image at the bottom and a dynamic animated button on top). I think maybe I can draw each bitmap to a separate off screen buffer then compose them back onto the swap chain, but that seems a little inefficient so I have not tried it. Direct Composition seems to serve this exact purpose but I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: From what you describe, Direct Composition is exactly meant for that. Why don't you use opacity (IDCompositionVisual3::SetOpacity)? Also, you must not draw all the time, you're supposed to "compose" once. A reproducing sample would help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier I added some code to describe the rendering logic. I didn't use the various SetProperty functions because the existing code expect an ID2D1RenderTarget* to draw on. Is there a way to draw directly onto a visual?

Comment: You don't have to use Windows paint loop with Direct Composition. I recommend you (re)start from scratch, read about it (and possible to upgrade Window::UI::Composition which is like Direct Composition version 3.x) using this seminal sample from Kenny Kerr https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62923cdacaba28fedc4f3dab6e0c12ec And you can also google for "kenny kerr direct composition" it will bring all good articles about this technology. Or post a complete reproducible example. Devil hides in details.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you I will look into it. I did read Kenny Kerr's articles (they are the reason I decided to try Direct Composition in the first place), and from what I gathered Direct Composition is not intended to be used in the way I described above. I tried using two swap chains instead, each as the content of a visual. This seems to work, I'm not sure is this recommended though.